# How to increase the quoted UPS shipping rate by 10% markup?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, shipping, ups

I have a website running Magento 2.4.6 that is tied into UPS Xml. I need to take the quoted UPS rates displayed to the customer and add a 10% markup to the quoted shipping price from UPS. Is there a way to do this by modifying the UPS extension?

Comment: Which module are you using for UPS?